# How to update a field in a post array Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I have a custom field value that gets set at checkout form .
I want to update that custom field from the post array.

I`ve tried getting the current value and then setting it to a new value.

```
$thisarray = $array;
  $arraykeys = array_keys($thisarray);
   $obj =   $array[$arraykeys[4]];  
        Mage::log($obj,true);
       $obj->setData('custom_field_four','Data Value Changed');
```

Please assist.

Comment: Upload your full code and values of array

Comment: 2018-10-25T13:19:35+00:00 ALERT (1): Array
(
    [method] => accountpayment
    [custom_field_one] => 8212225222412
    [custom_field_two] => 3614
    [custom_field_three] => true
    [custom_field_four] => M-
    [checks] => 167
) - Thats my array to get the post array data i use the code above. i want to update custom_field_four after it was posted

Answer (score 0):

You can set the custom filed value in observer like below code.

```
$quote = $evt->getQuote();
$post = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getPost();
if(isset($post['custom']['ssn']))
{
    $var = $post['custom']['ssn'];
    $quote->setSsn($var);
}
```

For more details you can refer this link [Click me](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/10/06/magento-add-custom-fields-checkout-page/)